# easy_install -U setuptools need admin while in admin privilege

Tags: python, windows, installation

when I try to run

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

it throw me an error

```
error: [WinError 5] Aceess is denied
```

while I'm run it in command prompt with administrator mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the answer from: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.distutils.devel/2493

copy the easy_install.exe and .py file into same folder. For an example,

```
C:\folder1\
```

They try to install on the cmd using,

```
C:\>C:\folder1\easy_install.exe -U setuptools
```